# Trying to use AJAX in .Net Core IDentity Register Page with no luck. .Net Core 5.0 Razor Page Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

Trying to do some validation on values entered on the .Net Core Identity Register page using an Ajax call.

Here is my code

Register.cshtml

button code -

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Submit" >Create Account</button>
```

call code -

```
 $("#Submit").on('click', function (event) {

     debugger;
     var urlVal = $(location).attr('href') + "?handler=CheckvcNumber"
     debugger;

     $.ajax({
         Type:"POST",
         url: urlVal,
         beforeSend: function (xhr) {
             xhr.setRequestHeader("RequestVerificationToken",
                 $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
         },
         data: {
             "vcNumber": $("#VCNumberInput").val()
         },
         async: false,
         success: function (response) {
             debugger;
             $('#RegisterForm').submit();
         },
         failure: function (response) {
             debugger;
             alert(JSON.stringify(response));
         },
         error: function (response) {
             debugger;
             alert(JSON.stringify(response));
         }
     });
 });
```

The urlVal = 'http://localhost:53196/Identity/Account/Register?handler=CheckvcNumber'

In Register.cshtml.cs

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class RegisterModel : PageModel
```

.
.
.

```
public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostCheckvcNumberAsync(string vcNumber)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vcNumber)) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(vcNumber));  
    return new JsonResult(new { message = "Unauthorized" });
}
```

When I run the code it goes straight to the successfunction in the Ajax call.  Doesn't go to the OnPostCheckvcNumberAsyncmethod in Register.cshtml.cs

Hope someone can help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Doesn't go to the OnPostCheckvcNumberAsyncmethod in Register.cshtml.cs

Try to change `Type` lowercase:

```
$.ajax({
         Type:"POST",
           ...
```

into :

```
$.ajax({
         type:"POST",
          ...
```

result:

[image]

Comment: D'oh! Thank you Qing Guo.  That worked.